# Error while creating a procedure in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I'm working on a php project and i'm still a novice in error debugging.
whenever i try to execute the following code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertData(Name varchar(255),Description text)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO categories(name,description) VALUES (Name,Description);
END
```

i get an error stating (in phpmyadmin)

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: my current DB version is 10.1.28-MariaDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `DELIMITER` statement:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE insertData (
    in_Name varchar(255),
    in_Description text
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO categories(name, description)
        VALUES (in_Name, in_Description);
END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Notice that I also renamed in the input parameters so they are less likely to be confused with column names.  This is a good practice when writing stored procedures and functions.